# NullPointerException when calling method with (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, scenebuilder

When I call the login method in the LoginViewController class I receive a NullPointerException. I know that the user object is not null since it prints out the object with a toString. Do I have to register the Client and User class in the LoginView.fxml in some way? What Im trying to achieve is that when the user clicks on login the method should instantiate a new Client which sends the User object to the server.

Exception

```
User: Username Password
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dinnerTime.Client.sendToServer(Client.java:44)
    at dinnerTime.LoginViewController.login(LoginViewController.java:34)
    ... 58 more
```

Main.java

```
package dinnerTime;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane mainLayout;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        showLoginView();
    }

    private void showLoginView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("LoginView.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout, 540, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

LoginViewController.java

```
package dinnerTime;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class LoginViewController {
    @FXML
    private Main main;
    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;
    @FXML
    private Button login;
    @FXML
    private Button register;

    private Client client;

    private User user;

    @FXML
    public void login() throws IOException {
        client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 3250);
        client.start();
        user = new User(username.getText(), password.getText());
        System.out.println("User: " + user.toString());
        client.sendToServer(user);
    }
}
```

LoginView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="540.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="dinnerTime.LoginViewController">
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="540.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="122.0" fitWidth="124.0" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../images/dt-logo-original.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Dinner" textFill="#464646">
               <font>
                  <Font size="70.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="372.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Time" textFill="#464646">
               <font>
                  <Font size="70.0" />
               </font></Label>
            <Label layoutX="91.0" layoutY="155.0" text="Username" />
            <TextField layoutX="164.0" layoutY="151.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="216.0" />
            <Label layoutX="91.0" layoutY="213.0" text="Password" />
            <PasswordField layoutX="164.0" layoutY="209.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="216.0" />
            <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="271.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="216.0" text="Login" />
            <Button layoutX="242.0" layoutY="352.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Register" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Client.java

```
package dinnerTime;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client extends Thread {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;

    public Client(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Object obj = ois.readObject();

                    if (obj instanceof Recipe) {

                    }


                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void sendToServer(Object obj) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package dinnerTime;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name, password;

    public User(String name, String password){
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you annotate `Client` and `User` with `@FXML`? Those classes are not nodes and they are not included nor in the FXML file nor in the scenegraph.

Comment: My bad, they are removed now. Still same exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) on the client's `oos` field. You initialize it in the `run()` method, which is executed on the background thread, but you try to access it in `sendToServer()` which is called from `login()` in the controller, and executed on the FX Application Thread.

Because these are on different threads, there is no guarantee as to which will be executed first: what is happening is that `sendToServer()` is getting executed before the background thread initializes `oos`, and hence `oos.writeObject(...)` is throwing a null pointer exception.

To fix this, you need to ensure that you do not call `sendToServer()` until the client is fully connected. One approach is to provide a callback of some kind to execute when the connection is established:

```
public class Client extends Thread {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;

    private Runnable onConnected ;

    public void setOnConnected(Runnable onConnected) {
        this.onConnected = onConnected ;
    }

    public Client(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();

            if (onConnected != null) {
                onConnected.run();
            }

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Object obj = ois.readObject();

                    if (obj instanceof Recipe) {

                    }


                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void sendToServer(Object obj) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
@FXML
public void login() throws IOException {
    client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 3250);
    user = new User(username.getText(), password.getText());
    client.setOnConnected(() -> client.sendToServer(user));
    client.start();
}
```